# How do I get myBatis update statement to commit in a Java Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, commit, mybatis, maven-jetty-plugin

I have Java Spring application running in a jetty-maven plugin. When I call a myBatis insert statement, the statement is automatically committed. However, when I call update, the statement is not committed. Per the myBatis documentation (http://www.mybatis.org/spring/transactions.html):

*You cannot call SqlSession.commit(), SqlSession.rollback() or SqlSession.close() over a Spring managed SqlSession.*

How do I configure my application to auto commit on a myBatis update statement?

I enabled logging. Here is what the log states on updates:

2012-12-12 17:20:31,669 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - Creating a new SqlSession
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,669 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@19e86f9] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,669 DEBUG   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,669 DEBUG   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test/test]
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,684 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] - JDBC Connection [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@af7eaf] will not be managed by Spring
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,684 DEBUG   [com.persistence.MyMapper.updateMyItem] - ooo Using Connection [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@af7eaf]
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,684 DEBUG   [com.persistence.MyMapper.updateMyItem] - ==>  Preparing: update myTable set date=? where id=?
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,700 DEBUG   [com.persistence.MyMapper.updateMyItem] - ==> Parameters: 2012-11-26 00:00:00.0(Timestamp), 0(Integer)
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,700 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@19e86f9]
 2012-12-12 17:20:31,700 DEBUG   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

On insert, the log is:

2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - Creating a new SqlSession
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@22da8f] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://test/test]
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] - JDBC Connection [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@3af3cb] will not be managed by Spring
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [com..persistence.MyMapper.insertMyItem] - ooo Using Connection [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@3af3cb]
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [com.persistence.MyMapper.insertMyItem] - ==>  Preparing: insert into myTable (id,date) values (?, ?)
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [com.persistence.MyMapper.insertMyItem] - ==> Parameters: 5(Integer), 2012-11-26 00:00:00.0(Timestamp)
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@22da8f]
 2012-12-12 16:35:53,932 DEBUG   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

The insert and update log statements seem to indicate the same basic steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found that it was a client issue. It was always passing a 0 for the id in the update statement. The records have ids > 0. Along the way, I configured spring txn management. It was at that point that I observed the same behavior and realized it must be something other than server side configuration issue. Sorry about not catching that prior to posting.